# What is more efficient? Using .replace() or passing string to list

Tags: python, string, performance

Solving the following problem from CodeFights:

> Given two strings, find the number of common characters between them.
>   For s1 = "aabcc" and s2 = "adcaa", the output should be
>   commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) = 3.
>
> Strings have 3 common characters - 2 "a"s and 1 "c".

The way I approached it, whenever I took a letter into account I wanted to cancel it out so as not to count it again. I know **strings** are immutable, even when using methods such as `.replace()` ([replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) method returns a copy of the string, no the actual string changed).

In order to mutate said `string` what I tend to do at the start is simply pass it on to a list with `list(mystring)` and then mutate that.

***Question is***... what is more efficient of the following? Take into account that option B gets done over and over, worst case scenario the strings are equal and have a match for match. Meanwhile option A happens once.

Option A)

```
list(mystring)
```

Option B)

```
mystring = mystring.replace(letterThatMatches, "")
```

Comment: Have you tried timing them? Also, option A does not do any work with said list, so those aren't really equivalent.

Comment: Neither, just make a `set` of both strings and ask for the intersection.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: a set will not take the *number* of `a`s, etc. into account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea of calling `replace` on the string for each element you find, is simply not a good idea: it takes *O(n)* to do that. If you do that for every character in the other string, it will result in an *O(m×n)* algorithm with *m* the number of characters of the first string, and *n* the number of characters from the second string.

You can simply use two `Counter`s, then calculate the minimum of the two, and then calculate the sum of the counts. Like:

```
from collections import Counter

def common_chars(s1,s2):
    c1 = Counter(s1) # count for every character in s1, the amount
    c2 = Counter(s2) # count for every character in s2, the amount
    c3 = c1 & c2 # produce the minimum of each character
    return sum(c3.values()) # sum up the resulting counts
```

Or as a *one-liner*:

```
def common_chars(s1,s2):
    return sum((Counter(s1) & Counter(s2)).values())
```

If dictionary lookup can be done in *O(1)* (which usually holds for an average case), this is an *O(m+n)* algorithm: the counting then happens in *O(m)* and *O(n)* respectively, and calculating the minimum runs in the number of different characters (which is at most *O(max(m,n))*. Finally taking the sum is again an *O(max(m,n))* operation.

For the sample input, this results in:

```
>>> common_chars("aabcc","adcaa")
3
```